# How to use serialize.js in simple form input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use `` in simple form input?

[Serialize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)

I tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jstab/css/standalone/selectize.css">
<script src="jstab/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jstab/css/standalone/selectize.css">


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#id_tag').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
});
        </script>

</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="tag" id="id_tag"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

but does not work. (nothing happens in input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it inside `document.ready()` because you have to wait that dom elements are ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#id_tag').selectize({
      delimiter: ',',
      persist: false,
      create: function(input) {
          return {
              value: input,
              text: input
          }
      }
   });
});
```